# Mouse and Touch events not working as expected

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to add a mouse and touch `down` and `move` event. In the events function, I want to get the `clientX` amount. I did the following to get it:

```
console.log(e.touches[0].clientX || e.clientX);
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

When:

- The mouse hovers over the orange box.
- The mouse clicks on `window`.
- I touch `window`. (I also get the correct output though. So it seems like it's the function fires twice.)

How can I add a touch and mouse `down` and `move` event, then get `clientX`? I have to add both touch and move event, because on a touchscreen laptop, there's both capability's. (I'm using Chrome.)

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
window.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownFunction);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', mouseDownFunction);

myDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveFunction);
myDiv.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseMoveFunction);

function mouseDownFunction(e) {
  console.log(e.touches[0].clientX || e.clientX);
}

function mouseMoveFunction(e) {
  myDiv.innerHTML = e.touches[0].clientX || e.clientX;
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

Make expression as `(e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX`

e.touches is undefined therefore you got the error.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
window.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownFunction);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', mouseDownFunction);

myDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveFunction);
myDiv.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseMoveFunction);

function mouseDownFunction(e) {
  console.log((e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX);
}

function mouseMoveFunction(e) {
  myDiv.innerHTML = (e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX;
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```